# How can I keep Html element hide() without using jQuery and show using jQuery.show()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make my htmlelement hide while the page renders. For this I set `display:none`. However, when I use $.show(), the element isn't showing up. I want to make the element show using $.show() itself. Please help!

Comment: @tamilmani The question is clear! Please understand what the OP wants and then post comments or answers.

Comment: Looks like you are not waiting until the `DOM` is ready .. Encase you code inside `$(function() {  })`;

Comment: Try by using visibility. I also faced the same problem in my code and i used visibility  it got solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. jQuery or the browser rendering engine has a problem with this. If you are not using any animation, you can very well define a class:

```
.hidden {display: none;}
```

And using jQuery, you can remove the class by:

```
$(element).hide().removeClass("hidden").fadeIn();
$(element).toggleClass("hidden");
```

Now, this on execution, hides the DOM, removes the CSS class and then fades in!

Comment: Yes, I'm using animation. I want to fadeIn()

Comment: Okay. Then you can do this way. Check the updated answer in a few seconds. `:P`

Comment: @SubinJacob Updated. Check! :)

Comment: I didn't down voted. your answer was suitable for me. Atleast u the one who read the question carefully. why should I?

Comment: @SubinJacob I didn't say you, buddy, I know that you didn't. I am generally saying. This happens a lot of times! Sorry, if it accidentally meant you! :(

Comment: Not something that users could ask, but yes, have upvoted! :)

Comment: ha ha ha. Thank you. Will u please add your 5 years experience to my 10 months

Comment: @SubinJacob Yes, love to, but I don't understand what I should do! :P

Comment: Help me! subinjacob@yahoo.com. So that no one will down vote or close vote my question.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code:

```
$("element_Selector").css("display","block");
```

Comment: This is jquery. I want to do it before jQuery Loads

Comment: @SubinJacob Not getting what you want. Can you explain more so that I can help you much better. as you are asking it the question according to that the answer will be above.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there might be 2 issues in such cases..

Either you are not waiting until the `DOM` is ready .. Encase you code inside `$(function() {  })`;

Else `style="display:none"`

Is taking precedence and your div will never be seen.

To counter that add a class to the element.   `.hide { display : none }`

And then `$(selector).show()` should get the work done.